# Redo wrong merge in GIT

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-merge-conflict

Long time ago in the git history I can see that someone did a wrong merge of two branches. He had a conflict, so he simply deleted a lot of the conflicted changes. The result is that the main branch doesn't contain these changes (and we didn't even suspect it until we checked).

Branch *feature* was merged into branch *development*. *Feature* contains changes X Y Z. However, Y and Z were deleted during the merge, so *development* only contains X. I want to merge *feature* into *development* again, because I need all changes. However, GIT thinks that they are already merged (it knows that they conflicted and were manually "resolved").

How can I do this merge?

Some notes:

- I cannot simply merge, the changes are not visible at all.
- I cannot cherry-pick, it doesn't work.
- I don't want to "just copy the files and commit them again" because that would mean that GIT failed in a crucial use-case
- I tried using different git merging strategies with partial success, but each strategy leaves out some files and in the end I don't have all the changes in *development*

Of course merging *feature* into a *new branch* (that starts from a *development* commit, just before the wrong commit) works. I can see all necessary changes. But again, I can't merge this *new branch* into *development* due to the reasons above.

Comment: What do you mean cherry-pick does not work? It alerts again about conflict, but then it can be manually solved... but hopefully right this time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redo bad git conflict resolution after push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43007243/redo-bad-git-conflict-resolution-after-push)

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the git book section on how to undo merges: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging#_undoing_merges

It recommends using git revert to undo the merge commit. And to solve the problem of re-merging (as git complains that those commits are already in the history) it recomments reverting the revert (instead of trying to merge again).