# How to get the original conflicted diff after having solved a merge conflict and staged the solution

Tags: git, git-merge, git-diff, merge-conflict-resolution

A convention that we have is that, when a merge conflict occurs, after solving it, the original conflicted diff should be added to the commit message, to help developers who may later try to figure out if a bad merge occurred.

The usual way that I do this is

```
git diff >conflict_log
```

and then I copy paste this into the commit message afterwards.

There are a few drawbacks to that workflow that I would like to improve:

- You might forget to save the `conflict_log` first, and then developers often end up redoing the merge to be able to get the original diff
- Copy pasting the whole diff may be more difficult if the diff is large and you are working over an ssh session

What I would like to do is make a `prepare-commit-msg` hook that will automatically add this diff to the commit message.

The problem I have is that at the time that `prepare-commit-msg` is run, the index has already been changed so `git diff` works differently and doesn't just show the original conflicts anymore.

I have tried using versions like

```
git diff hash hash^1 hash^2
```

And in the documentation here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging
under "Combined Diff Format" it is suggested to use

```
git diff --cc
```

But I'm not sure,

- should I be using `HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, given that I'm trying to do this in `prepare-commit-msg` before the merge commit has actually been committed?
- I want to get the diff that git generates with the `<<<<<<` markers from conflict resolution, before the user started resolving them, but at the time that `prepare-commit-msg` runs, the user has already staged their resolutions, is there a way I can take the diff against that state of the index, instead of the current state?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43007243/redo-bad-git-conflict-resolution-after-push (in that both questions are ultimately trying to solve a similar problem)

Comment: @RobinGreen I think they are related but it's not a duplicate. I'm specifically trying to write a script that can be used in a `prepare-commit-msg` hook, and I'm trying to figure out if there's a cleaner way to do it other than stashing the user's changes, trying to restore the index state, then take a diff, then reapply the user's changes, which might all work but is complex and might be brittle in practice. The answer to that question doesn't really give me any leads here.

Comment: OK, let me spell out what I had in mind then: if you use the approach in that question's top answer whenever you want to solve a bad merge, you won't need to have stored the conflicted merge state, because you can just regenerate it.